# TCP /RTMP handshake

Tags: tcp, rtmp

I'm writing an application to (unofficially) replace a client made in adobe air, they use RTMP as the connection protocol which i'll have to create my own class to implement it :<

RTMP as far as I know is placed under the TCP protocol, but do I have to establish a TCP connection /handshake first, followed by an RTMP handshake?

Or is the TCP handshake ignored and the TCP headers are just used to transport the RTMP handshake /data?

Kind regards.

Answer (score 3):

You establish TCP connection and then you immediately proceed with RTMP handshake, i.e. you start with sending C0, then go S0, C1, S1, C2, S2. As soon as you receive the latter, RTMP handshake is complete. Good luck with RTMP, you will need it.

Answer (score 1):

Wow, a good project you have there.

RTMP is over TCP as you suggested. The interesting thing is that not only control commands but also media data is sent over TCP. Unlike RTSP which uses UDP as expected. There are also libraries that do what you re trying to do. One that I found interesting is written in php - http://code.google.com/p/php-rtmp-client/.

You also need to work with AMF which is the binary format in which RTMP commands are encoded with. There is a good Wikipedia article about it and a few parsers out there like AMFPHP

Answer (score 0):

in case anyone stumbled over this on Google looking for a solution like I did, I found mine in http://www.fluorinefx.com/. No need to worry about handshakes or anything. It's all wrapped neatly :)